# Mistakes in $\lim_{a\to \infty}(a^2 - a) = - \frac{1}{6}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fake-proofs

One can say, using Ramanujan summation or the zeta function regularization, that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k=- \frac{1}{12}$. Using this result I've gotten a very confusing and counterintuitive result, which I suspect it's wrong, but I can't see any mistakes in the reasoning. Could you tell me if it's right or not and where is the mistake?
Consider a number $a \in N$, then it's square can be written as:
$$a^2 = (a-1)^2 + 2(a-1) + 1$$ 
$$a^2 = (a-2)^2 + 2(a-2) + 1 + 2(a-1) + 1 $$
$$a^2 = (a-3)^2 + 2(a-3) + 1 + 2(a-2) + 1 + 2(a-1) + 1$$
$$...$$
$$a^2 = (a-a)^2 + 2(1+2+3+...+(a-1)) + a$$
$$a^2 = a + 2\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} k$$
Then:
$$a^2 - a = 2\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} k$$
Taking limits on both sides:
$$\lim_{a\to \infty}(a^2 - a) = \lim_{a\to \infty}2\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} k$$
Using the result from above we get:
$$\lim_{a\to \infty}(a^2 - a) = 2(- \frac{1}{12}) = - \frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Ramanujan summation is a property of a sum

Comment: Why do you accept that the sum of the positive integers is $-1/12$?

Comment: Ramanujan summation is not the limit of the sum you have written, the limit of the sum you have written is obviously $\infty$, that is the origin of the "contradiction". A summation method, such as that of Ramanujan, or e.g. Pade or many others, is a way to assign a value to a divergent series, which is not the value one assigns to ordinary infinite sums (and such method recovers the correct result for convergent series)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your working is admirable, your final step of 'taking limits' is completely undefined, i.e., ask yourself, what are you really doing when you 'take limits' in this context? What definition or process are you referring to?

If you are using the usual, elementary calculus notion of 'limit', then you have a divergent limit 'equalling' a divergent limit - it doesn't make sense to 'take' such a limit.

If you want to use (in)famous 'identity' $1+2+3+\ldots=-1/12$, then you have even more problems to worry about: firstly, it's vague as to what the symbol $\lim$ now means in your argument; secondly, it's not clear that, under whatever definition of $\lim$ you fix upon, $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}2\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} k=2\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} k$, and so you cannot necessarily conclude that $\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}2\sum_{k=1}^{a-1} k=-1/6$.

That being said, I rather enjoyed your round-about way of proving the well-known formula $\sum_{k=1}^{a} k = a(a+1)/2$. It's just the 'taking limits' part that makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It looked very confuse to me, but now I can see my mistake.